# Generic reflection, how to get a list?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following piece of code:

```
var prop = FindEntityProperty(entityName);

if(prop==null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("entityName: " + entityName);
}

var db = new DatabaseContext();
Type returnType = prop.PropertyType;

var col = (prop.GetValue(db) as ???);
Data = col.ToList(); //or something IEnumerable<?>
```

Situation looks that, I have `PropertyInfo` named `prop` here).
I'm sure this property is `DbSet<Τ>`. I don't know what type is `T` (only that it's a class). But because it's generic `DbSet`, it can be treated like a generic IEnumarble.
So, because `propertyInfo.GetValue()` return a simple object, Ι need to cast my collection.

How can I do this?

I know it's a bad practice in programming. Here I'm doing it only for learning reflection.

Comment: What exactly do you want? An `ArrayList`? Or an `array`? Or a `List<T>`? Or something else?

Comment: `DbSet`'s superclass `DbQuery` implements `IEnumerable` so you can just cast it to that.

Comment: I want List<T> or IEnumerable<T>

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to cast `prop` as `DbSet<T>`?

Comment: How to cast any object, to a generic type, without knowing a 'subtype'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar problem like that, i wanted to create a method that gives me the object back from the database, so created this piece of code.
I hope this helps you:

Put this into your DatabaseContainer:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find<TEntity>(Dictionary<string, object> findValues = null) where TEntity : EntityObject
    {
        var entities = this.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>().ToList();

        if (findValues!= null && findValues.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in findValues)
            {
                if(item.Value != null)
                    entities = entities.DynamicContains<TEntity>(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }

        return entities;
    }
```

And put this into a extention class:

```
public static List<TEntity> DynamicContains<TEntity>(this IEnumerable<TEntity> entities, string propertyName, object item)
    {
        List<TEntity> comparingEntities = new List<TEntity>();
        foreach (var obj in entities)
        {
            var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(String) && ((string)property.GetValue(obj, new object[] { })).ToLower().Contains(item.ToString().ToLower()))
                comparingEntities.Add(obj);

            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Boolean) && ((bool)property.GetValue(obj, new object[] { })) == (bool)item)
                comparingEntities.Add(obj);     
        }

        return comparingEntities;
    }
```

Usage:

```
Dictionary<string, object> findValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
findValues.Add("Name", "Tom");
findValues.Add("Age", 4);

var list1 = db.Find<Person>(findValues); // Returns a list of persons that includes the find values.
var list2 = db.Find<Person>() // Returns all persons in the database.
```

Comment: EntityObject it's what I looking for. Thank you!